# undefined method id for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, null

I'm getting this error in RoR:

> Started POST "/conversations?person_id=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-10 15:03:09 -0200
>   Processing by ConversationsController#create as JS
>     Parameters: {"person_id"=>"3"}
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
>
> app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb:3:in `create'

My conversation_controller:

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
 def create
 @conversation = Conversation.get(current_person.id, params[:person_id])

 add_to_conversations unless conversated?

 respond_to do |format|
   format.js
 end
end

def close
  @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])

  session[:conversations].delete(@conversation.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

private

def add_to_conversations
  session[:conversations] ||= []
  session[:conversations] << @conversation.id
end

def conversated?
  session[:conversations].include?(@conversation.id)
end
end
```

Conversation model:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: Person
  belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: Person

  validates :sender_id, uniqueness: { scope: :recipient_id }

  scope :between, -> (sender_id, recipient_id) do
  where(sender_id: sender_id, recipient_id: recipient_id).or(
    where(sender_id: recipient_id, recipient_id: sender_id)
  )
end

def self.get(sender_id, recipient_id)
  conversation = between(sender_id, recipient_id).first
  return conversation if conversation.present?

  create(sender_id: sender_id, recipient_id: recipient_id)
end

def opposed_person(person)
  person == recipient ? sender : recipient
end
end
```

conversation create.js

```
var conversations = $('#conversations-list');
var conversation = conversations.find("[data-conversation-id='" + "<%=     @conversation.id %>" + "']");

if (conversation.length !== 1) {
   conversations.append("<%= j(render 'conversations/conversation',    conversation: @conversation, person: current_person) %>");
   conversation = conversations.find("[data-conversation-id='" + "<%=      @conversation.id %>" + "']");
 }

conversation.find('.panel-body').show();

var messages_list = conversation.find('.messages-list');
var height = messages_list[0].scrollHeight;
messages_list.scrollTop(height);
```

Comment: `current_person` is nil. Find out why.

Comment: Does this happen during AJAX request?

Comment: Sorry, but what is AJAX? This code is part of a live messenger aplication in RoR. The error happens when I click in a person to start a conversation.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to be returning nil

```
 @conversation = Conversation.get(current_person.id, params[:person_id])
```

If you don't have the ability to debug with a breakpoint you could do:

```
puts "#{current_person.id} | #{params[:person_id]} | #{@conversation.to_sql}"
```

The see what is off.

I imagine current_person is set up elsewhere like the current_user in devise.

Comment: Yeah, my devise is not the User, but Person because of the application purpose.

Comment: That `puts` will never print anything :)